# Data loss scenarios while restarting a streaming query with Kafka as source

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

In the book "Spark Streaming with Apache Spark", the authors mention that the field "failOnDataLoss (default: true)" should be set to false while testing with Kafka as the source. They say,

> This flag indicates whether to fail the restart of a streaming query
>   in case data might be lost. This is usually when offsets are out of
>   range, topics are deleted, or topics are rebalanced. We recommend
>   setting this option to false during the develop/test cycle because
>   stop/restart of the query side with a continuous producer will often
>   trigger a failure. Set this back to true for production deployment.

I want to understand why would there be failures in stopping/restarting the query. How would offsets get out of range? Doesn't Spark maintain what offsets to read as checkpointing?

Answer (score 0):

I aggree that the reason "because stop/restart of the query side with a continuous producer will often trigger a failure" does not really make sense. As you said, Spark maintains the current offsets. In addition, stopping/restarting the query while having a continuous producer is exactly what we aim for on a productive system.

Therefore, I could only guess what is meant by that statement and my best guess is that there is a typo and it should have been written "**without** a continuous producer".

You usually do not have a continuous producer on development environments and, to save some disk space, you usually have a short retention period in your topic on a development environment.

During the development phase you produce a few messages manually to your input topic and run your Spark Structured Streaming job to see if it behaves as expected. Let's say you have produces messages with offsets 0 to 10. Then, someone in your team want to test another consumer on that topic and produces messages with offsets 11 to 20. After a while, in the next development phase (assume it is 3 weeks later) you want to test another feature for which you will again manually produce some messages. However, the cleanup policy of your Kafka topic already removed all old offsets 0 to 20 and when restarting your streaming query it tries to read offset 11 which does not exist anymore.

Another common scenario is when you remove all data on development environment from a topic to be able to "start from scratch".

These scenarios often show up on development environments and it is therefore recommended to set the option `failOnDataLoss` to `false`.